# EditText Android and inner information

Tags: android

I need to achieve the similar behavior from the image below. I need to add extra static information inside an EditText in android that does not change according to the user's input (except for the character count).

[image: EditText with extra data]

How do I achieve this? As per I see from the focus, the data is inside the EditText and not out, so i believe this is some sort of style or a custom component.

Many Thanks
T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make a view group with the text how you want it with an `EditText` at the top for the user input, then set the background of your view group to `android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"`

Answer (score 0):

use setText() method of EditText with the appropriate  [BufferType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.BufferType.html)

for the top text, and [setHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28int%29) for the bottom one.

Comment: It does work that way. hint disappears when the text is being inserted.